# WebView return null pointer exception

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-webview

I have a problem with webview in android.
this is the code of the class webview:

```
public class WebViewsActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.web_views);
        Intent thisIntent = getIntent();
        final String link = thisIntent.getExtras().getString("link");
        Log.e("link is :",link);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl(link);
    }
}
```

and this is the `Exception` :

> > 04-27 01:17:44.669  25210-25210/customlistviewvolley.androidhive.info.customlistviewvolley
> >     E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ GL_INVALID_OPERATION 04-27 01:17:46.889 
> >     25210-25210/customlistviewvolley.androidhive.info.customlistviewvolley
> >     E/link is :﹕
> >     http://www.lequipe.fr/Football/Actualites/Alexandre-lacazette-je-ne-compte-pas-m-arreter-la/554284#xtor=RSS-1
> >     04-27 01:17:46.929 
> >     25210-25210/customlistviewvolley.androidhive.info.customlistviewvolley
> >     E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> >         java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{customlistviewvolley.androidhive.info.customlistviewvolley/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.WebViewsActivity}:
> >     java.lang.NullPointerException
> >                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2338)
> >                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2388)
> >                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:148)
> >                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1319)
> >                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> >                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
> >                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5473)
> >                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
> >                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
> >                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:854)
> >                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:670)
> >                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
> >          Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
> >                 at info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.WebViewsActivity.onCreate(WebViewsActivity.java:24)
> >                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5234)
> >                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
> >                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302)
> >                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2388)
> >                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:148)
> >                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1319)
> >                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> >                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
> >                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5473)
> >                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
> >                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
> >                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:854)
> >                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:670)
> >                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Line 24 is : webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
The internet permission is added in manifest.

Comment: where did you instantiate it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the following line to get a reference to the WebView instance

```
WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.your_webview_id);
```

it should be added before

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl(link);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add this line   `webView  = new WebView(this);` to get the reference of webview before following lines

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl(link);
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't instantiate the webView field. This is indicated by this line in the log :

> dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.WebViewsActivity.onCreate(WebViewsActivity.java:24)